# How to use regex_replace to replace special characters from a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: regex, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

There is a column **batch** in dataframe. It has values like **'9%','$5'**, etc.

I need use `regex_replace` in a way that it removes the special characters from the above example and keep just the numeric part.

Examples like 9 and 5 replacing 9% and $5 respectively in the same column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df.withColumn("batch",regexp_replace(col("batch"), "/[^0-9]+/", ""))
```

Comment: creating a column `batch` with only numbers as value... Every thing apart from numbers will be replaced with blank

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. I tried your code and it worked fine. Thanks a lott

Comment: what if we want to do it for all columns in single command, please

Comment: @dileepvarma regex_replace can be used in `select`... df.select(regexp_replace(col("col1"), "/[^0-9]+/", ""),regexp_replace(col("col2"), "/[^0-9]+/", ""))

Comment: @undefined_variable I have 100's of columns so Its tough for me to add this statement for each column .is there any recursive way? thanks

Comment: @dileepvarma use `df.columns.map` to create the statement and use it in your select

Comment: `val cols = df.columns.map(x=>regexp_replace(col(x), "/[^0-9]+/", ""))`... df.select(cols:_*)

Comment: `df.withColumns({"colName": expr("regexp_replace(colName, r'\+', '')").astype('float')}).show(15)
` Why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\W+
```

`\W` - matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far?

```
select regexp_replace("'$5','9%'","[^0-9A-Za-z]","")
```